# Editar imagen Ajax

Tags: laravel

Estoy adentrandome en laravel y me surgio un problema al tratar de editar unas imagenes.
al crear o registrar un producto con su respectiva imagen no hay problema ya que no uso ajax.
pero al momento de editar no puedo ingresar a los datos que genera el selector de la imagen

1: resultado en consola: https://ibb.co/nw3dwp

- Debido a esto no puedo cambiar a un nombre unico, copiar la imagen etc etc.

2: codigo ajax:

```
    $("#actualizar2").click(function()
    {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var unit_cost = $("#unit_cost").val();
        var image= $("#image").prop('files')[0];
        console.log(image);
        var route = "{{url('admin/products/')}}/"+id+"";
        var token = $("#token").val();
        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        data: { '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',name:name,unit_cost:unit_cost,image:image},
        success: function(data){
         if (data.success == 'true')
         {
            console.log(data);

            /*$("#modal-EProduct").modal('toggle');
            window.location = '{{ route('products.index')}}' ;*/

           }
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            $("#error").html(data.responseJSON.name);
            $("#message-error").fadeIn();
            if (data.status == 422) {
               console.clear();
            }

        }  
      });
    });
```

3: controlador: https://ibb.co/nre1Gp

public function update(Request $request, $id
{
$product = Product::FindOrFail($id);
$nameFile =$request->file('image');

return response()->json(['success'=>'true','data'=>$nameFile])
}

4: html -> boton que llama al modal

```
                    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-EProduct">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick='Mostrar({{$product->id}});' id="#modal-EProduct{{ $product->id }}" data-original-title="Editar"  data-target='#modal-EProduct' data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i>
                    </a>  
                    </span>
```

--- Modal

{!! Form::open([ 'id'=> 'form','autocomplete'=>'off']) !!}
      
        
          ×
          Editanto Producto

```
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token">
      <input type="hidden" id="id">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              {!! Form::label('name','Nombre del Producto') !!}
            {!! Form::text(
              'name',null,
              ['class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder' =>'Nombre del Producto',
              'required']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            {!! Form::label('unit_cost','Precio Unitario') !!}
            {!! Form::text(
              'unit_cost',null,
              ['class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder' =>'Precio Unitario',
              'required','onkeypress'=>"return valida(event)"]) !!}
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('image','Imagen') !!}
          <img id="url" src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" height="15%" width="15%">
          {!! Form::file(
            'image',
            ['class'=>'file','data-preview-file-type'=>'text']
          ) !!}
      </div>

    </div>
       {!! Form::close() !!}
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      {!!link_to('#', $title='Actualizar2', $attributes = ['id'=>'actualizar2', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

al usar el modal para editar la imagen se me complico y no eh hallado una ayuda googleando espero su ayuda.
oh algun consejo u ejemplo de como puedo editar datos usando un modal,
evitando crear un modal por cada registro (es lo que evito al usar ajax).
de ante mano gracias

Comment: Por favor pon tu código en tu pregunta, en lugar de esos links a capturas de pantalla. Así será más fácil ayudarte. Además, también sería útil el código HTML para entender bien lo que hace tu javascript.

Comment: espero que no sea largo

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#modal-EProduct').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var name = button.data('name') 
    var unit_cost =button.data('unit_cost')  
    var product_id =button.data('productid')  
    var url =button.data('url')  
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #unit_cost').val(unit_cost);
    modal.find('.modal-body #url').attr("src","/images/products/"+url);
    modal.find('.modal-body #product_id').val(product_id);
    });
```

solucione de esta manera, de todos modos aun quisiera saber como realizar con ajax

Comment: es como crear varios modal, solo que no los crea
solo llena los datos que necesito en los DATA del boton que llama al modal
y el proceso es el mismo, enviar a la ruta de edicion , route('x.update')